# Splitting a string by multiple keywords and creating a dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split, regex-group

After doing some web scraping i was finally able to get a string from a font body, and it comes out as follows

```
string = Date:  02/13/2020  Court Time:  1030  Court Room:  0206  Microfilm:  SD000000000
```

The final thing i need to figure out about my code, and i guess it seems rather trivial at this point, would be to split that string into dictionary pairs where the pairing would look like:

```
Date:  02/13/2020,
Court Time:  1030,  
Court Room:  0206,  
Microfilm:  SD000000000
```

I thought of maybe doing something such as:

```
keywords = ['Date:','Court Time:','Court Room:', 'Microfilm:']
for k in keywords:
            print(string.split())
```

Using those keywords as delimiters. 
but it spat this out multiple times

```
['Date:', '02/13/2020', 'Court', 'Time:', '1030', 'Court', 'Room:', '0206', 'Microfilm:', 'SD000000000']
['Date:', '02/13/2020', 'Court', 'Time:', '1030', 'Court', 'Room:', '0206', 'Microfilm:', 'SD000000000']
['Date:', '02/13/2020', 'Court', 'Time:', '1030', 'Court', 'Room:', '0206', 'Microfilm:', 'SD000000000']
['Date:', '02/13/2020', 'Court', 'Time:', '1030', 'Court', 'Room:', '0206', 'Microfilm:', 'SD000000000']
```

Comment: Yeah cause you're doing `for k in keywords`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your example:

```
s='Date:  02/13/2020  Court Time:  1030  Court Room:  0206  Microfilm:  SD000000000'
```

Assuming that a double space is your separator:

```
sep = '  '
lst = s.split(sep)
d = dict(zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2]))
```

The output is:

```
 {'Date:': '02/13/2020',
  'Court Time:': '1030',
  'Court Room:': '0206',
  'Microfilm:': 'SD000000000'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use regular expressions and build the pattern for the list of keywords:

```
pattern = '|'.join(['(' + i + ')' for i in keywords])
```

this gives `'(Date:)|(Court Time:)|(Court Room:)|(Microfilm:)'`

We can now split the string with that pattern:

```
lst = re.split(pattern, string)
```

which gets here: `['', 'Date:', None, None, None, '  02/13/2020  ', None, 'Court Time:', None, None, '  1030  ', None, None, 'Court Room:', None, '  0206  ', None, None, None, 'Microfilm:', '  SD000000000']`

Let us post process the list to extract the keys and values for the final dict:

```
def getkey(ls):
    for i in ls:
        if i is not None:
            return i.strip().rstrip(':')

lk = len(keywords)
elts = [(lst[i: i+lk)], lst[i+lk]) for i in range(1, len(lst), lk+1)]
resul = {getkey(i): j.strip() for i,j in elts}
```

This gives as expected for result:

```
{'Date': '02/13/2020', 'Court Time': '1030', 'Court Room': '0206', 'Microfilm': 'SD000000000'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following piece of code would do the trick.

```
my_string = "Date:  02/13/2020, Court Time:  1030, Court Room:  0206,  Microfilm:  SD000000000"
key_value_pair = [line.split(':') for line in my_string.split(',')]
output_dict = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in key_value_pair}
print(output_dict)
```

Output :

```
{'Date': '02/13/2020', 'Court Time': '1030', 'Court Room': '0206', 'Microfilm': 'SD000000000'}
```

Comment: This works, too, but mine didn't have commas so it'd be split('  ') instead of split(',')